# Agnostic query learning of decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, fourier-analysis, pac-learning

Gopalan, Kalai, Klivans gave an algorithm 
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1374376.1374451
for agnostically learning decision trees $h:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ under the uniform distribution given black-box query access to a target function. They use discrete Fourier analysis. Question: How might one extend this to learning decision trees over $\mathbb{R}^n$? Obviously there is no "uniform distribution", unless we limit the domain to a (say) ball, which I'm perfectly happy to do.

Comment: A hazy idea: their proof doesn't extend to the Gaussian measure, using Hermite instead of Fourier (and mimicking the argument)?

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea, I'll give it some thought.